# Not able to get count using JDBC connection

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm not able to get the number of rows by making a query. I've used JDBC connection for it. But, rather it doesn't show any error, but it stops executing the process.

Here is my code

```
Transaction transaction=null;
    Connection c = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet result;
    try {
         Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
         c = DriverManager.getConnection(
         "jdbc:postgresql://192.168.1.7:5432/"+userDB,
     "postgres", "openerp");
     } catch (Exception e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
         System.err.println(e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage());
         System.exit(0);
     }
    int count = 0;
    try {   
        LOGGER.info("In try of get");
        factory = HibernateUtil.connectDB(userDB);
        LOGGER.info("Connected to DB");
        //Open Session
        session = factory.openSession();
        //Begin Transaction
        transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        LOGGER.info("Beginning the transaction");
        stmt = c.createStatement();
        String sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM mycontent_messages where status = '0'";

        count = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
        LOGGER.info("successfully got count : "+count);
        c.commit();
        stmt.close();
        c.close();
```

Exception which I'm getting is

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: A result was returned when none was expected.
at    org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:307)
at net.vsspl.mycontent.daoimpl.contentImpl.getUnreadCount(contentImpl.java:379)
at net.vsspl.mycontent.services.countUnreadMessages.main(countUnreadMessages.java:49)
```

It logs upto "Beginning the transaction". After that it doesn't show anything. Is there any issue in my code?

Comment: Do you know that no exception is thrown? Do you log any exceptions thrown in the `try` block?

Comment: are you sure that status is of type varchar?

Comment: furthermore I dont think executeUpdate is correct for that sql :-)

Comment: Change `executeUpdate` to `executeQuery` I think?

Comment: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: A result was returned when none was expected.
 at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeUpdate(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:307)
 at net.vsspl.mycontent.daoimpl.contentImpl.getUnreadCount(contentImpl.java:379)
 at net.vsspl.mycontent.services.countUnreadMessages.main(countUnreadMessages.java:49)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to get the result set from the query and process it that way, not get the number of affected rows..

```
ResultSet rs =  stmt.executeQuery(sql);
 int count = 0;
 if(rs.next())
 {
    count = rs.getInt(1);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

> > count = stmt.executeUpdate(sql);

You're not executing an update; you're executing a query.

Answer (score 0):

here you are executing a query to fetch the count of the records so you should be using

```
resultSet = stmt.executeQuery(sql);
```